# tabular height savebox problem

Tags: tables, boxes, height

I'd like to build a **tabular** and next to it a **graphics in the same height**.
I use the following code (for minimal working purposes, I used `\rule`) and do not understand, what is going wrong:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    \newsavebox{\testbox}%
    \newlength{\testheight}%
    \savebox{\testbox}{%
            \begin{tabular}{cr}%
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\underline{\underline{\textsc{Line 1}}}}\\ \\
                Line&2\\%
                Line&3\\%
                Line&4\\%
            \end{tabular}%
        }%
        \settoheight{\testheight}{\usebox{\testbox}}
        \usebox{\testbox}\hfill\rule{3pt}{\the\testheight}\hfill\rule{3pt}{\the\testheight}
\end{document}
```

As `\savebox` if fragil, I also played around with the robust commands `\mbox` and/or `\sbox` - without success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default `tabular` is vertically centred so the height is only (roughly) half what you need.

Depending what you want to do you could use

```
           \begin{tabular}[b]{cr}%
```

so the table is bottom aligned, or you could extract the height *and* the depth of the box.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try [tabulatht](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/tabularht) from the [Oberdiek-bundle.](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek) The `tabularht` package defines some environments that add a height specification to `tabular` and `array` environments.

Comment: Sounds interesting - I'll have a look at it. Thanks.